# Why is Gaussian matrix full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-distribution, random-matrices

Suppose $A\in R^{n\times n}$ is a matrix with independent standard normal entries. Is there an elementary argument to show that $A$ is nonsingular with probability $1$?

Comment: A non-zero polynomial (here the determinant) in $n^2$ variables vanishes only in a set $N$ of measure zero. The probability of determinant vanishing is the integral of the continuous function (=a product of $n^2$ i.i.d. gaussians in distinct variables) over $N$. What do you know about integrals over sets of measure zero?